# Use if statement with Jekyll liquid to find a period in a string

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid, contains

Trying to set up some conditional rendering in Jekyll where if the string from my a data file has a period, I will show it.

```
{% assign member = {{members.basic_info.website}} %}
{% if member == nil or member contains "asd" or member contains "alesanchezr" or member contains " " %}
    <p>dont show</p>      
{% elsif  {{members.basic_info.website}} contains "."  %}
    <p>has period</p>
{% endif %}
```

Tried using contains ".", but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?
Here is my code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the elsif statement:

```
{% elsif  {{members.basic_info.website}} contains "."  %}
```

You don't need the curly braces here, as you're already inside a liquid tag. And you can refere to the `member` variable defined earlier. So the line should be:

```
{% elsif  member contains "."  %}
```